# Remove specific control onto one Master Page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, inline

I have placed an anchor link on one of the master page which would be visible where that master page is used. But in one of the page, I don't want an anchor link to be visible. Plus I have been directed not to use inline tag.

What can be done to remove anchor tag from one of the master pages?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your `Anchor` control is `runat='server'` then,
You could do this on your page where you want to remove that `Anchor`

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl Anchor =
                             this.Master.FindControl("AnchorID") as 
                             System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl;
if (Anchor != null)
     this.Master.Controls.Remove(Anchor);
```

Answer (score 0):

On your page which uses master page, you can retrieve the master something like this

```
MasterPageClassName mp = (MasterPageClassName)this.Master;
```

You can add public method in your master page class to showhide the anchor link (You will have access to all private controls on master page here)

```
mp.ToggleLink()
```

This ToggleLink method will actually show/hide your anchor button/control as per your business requirement.